# How do you store the contents of a POJO in the preference store?

Tags: android

I am looking to find a way to store the value of a POJO (containing Strings, booleans, ints) in a preference variable that I can then retrieve by the key used when I store it.
The POJO contains many String / boolean / int attributes, so I don't want to store them each individually. The problem I'm running into is that the only preference variable types are String, boolean, float, and int. Is there some way to convert the POJO to a String that I could then retrieve back per it's key and convert back to the POJO, sort of like casting it>
1) Populate the POJO
2) Convert the POJO to a String
3) Store the String in the preference Store with a key value (normal preference store stuff)
4) When needed, retrieve the data back from the preference store as a String and convert it back to the POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(instance);
objectOutputStream.flush();
val = Base64.encodeBase64String(outputStream.toByteArray()));
```

To deserialise:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(dataStr);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
try
{
     ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
     objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
     return (T)objectInputStream.readObject();
}
finally {
     if (objectInputStream != null)
        objectInputStream.close();
}
```

Where T is the object type.

Comment: This will only work if the POJO is `Serializable`, and then you have all the standard Java issues with that (e.g., versioning).

Comment: Thanks for the start. A couple of questions on your reply: 
1) Is 'val' in this a String (in the last part of converting a POJO to a String) version of the POJO that I'll then store in the Preference store to retrieve later?
2) When I get the String back, how do I convert the String back to my POJO?
3) I couldn't find Base64: what do I need to import for this? 
2)

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Updated answer 3) The Apache Commons Codec project contains a good Base64 implementation.